# Convert ObjectID (Mongodb) to String in java

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I work on my records that comes from a PHP API , that returns my MongoDB documents as JSON (json_enoded).

all I want is a simple function that gets the actual id from MongoId , like this :

This is the record that comes from API into my java application :

```
 String id =    cat.getString("_id");
 String id =   "{\"$id\":\"54f76bb7404f9990010041b2\"}"
```

and *cat* is a JsonObject that I get from my records;

and by the way , I get my records from an API that is written in PHP and all the responses from this API are json_encoded , So they are **Strings** actually .

I want this :

```
 String id =   54f76bb7404f9990010041b2
```

is there any easy way ?

EDIT : I'm not using JAva mongo driver , this documents are strings that comes from an Api.

Comment: Could you update your question with a sample document.

Comment: `String id =   {"$id":"54f76bb7404f9990010041b2"}` isn't really valid java. What exactly are you getting from `mongodb`? Don't you get a `org.bson.types.ObjectId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used @Aminda's answer and used this :

```
 String mongo_id = "{\"$id\":\"54f76bb7404f9990010041b2\"}"

 String MongoIdToString(String mongo_id){
    return mongo_id.split(":")[1].substring(mongo_id.indexOf("\"")).split("\"")[0];
}

  String mongo_id = MongoIdToString(mongo_id);
```

this will produce :

```
  mongo_id =  54f76bb7404f9990010041b2
```

Thanks to all;

Answer (score 1):

How about `String.split(":")` and then a `substring` from first index of " to last index? Sorry for describing in brief. I can provide a code example, if required.

```
String id = "{'$id':'54f76bb7404f9990010041b2'}";
String[] tokens = id.split(":");
String valueToken = tokens[1];
valueToken = valueToken.substring(1,valueToken.lastIndexOf("'"));
System.out.println(valueToken);
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what you are getting exactly in `String id =    cat.getString("_id");', because `{"$id":"54f76bb7404f9990010041b2"}` is not a valid String.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helps? I have edited the post with an example too.

Comment: Actually your answer still needs to remove the last accurance of " , This is the result of your answer :   54f76bb7404f9990010041b2"

Comment: Actually that is because I used a wrong String earlier by my own. Edited my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like (assuming your string is: `"{_id:....}"`:

```
String s = yourId.split["::][1];
String id = s.subString(0, s.length - 1);
```